# Pass variables from function to router(Same page)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question regarding Node.js that I started using recently and I don't have much dexterity yet.
So, I have a function inside the pages.js file and I need some values ​​to be passed to HTML in the same way that was done with "arrayOfCookies", (passing to the router that is also in pages.js). However what I understood is that the function needs to return next () for the page to be loaded. Is there any way to pass these values ​​(7 variables) to the router.get in a similar way to what I have already done with cookies? My goal is to display those in my HTML. I appreciate any help, my code is below - Im not going to put my function here cause i guess its not relevant to answer my question.

```
router.get('/userPage',beforeReq,authFunct,(req,res) =>{

var arrayOfCookies = req.cookies['myEmail'];
///exercises1,exercises2,exercises3,exercises4,exercises5,exercises6,exercises7 are the variables that i need to pass from my function to the line below. They are all arrays
res.render('userPage',  {name: arrayOfCookies})
```

And this is just a part of the function that I want to pass the values ​​of

```
function beforeReq(req,res,next){


var allExercises = []
var exercises1 = []
var exercises2 = []
var exercises3 = []
var exercises4 = []
var exercises5 = []
var exercises6 = []
var exercises7 = []



return next()
```

}

Comment: Assign the data to the `req` in the `beforeReq` function like so `req.allExercises = allExercises;` then use it in `render` function like so `res.render('userPage',  { name: arrayOfCookies, allExercises: req.allExercises })` But it's important to make sure you are not overwriting any existing properties on `req` object,

Comment: Thanks a lot, after a few tries, I managed to make it work.